# google bigquery visiualization

Tags: ios, google-bigquery

I want to visualize the data  present in big query by a  iOS app just like tableau . Any suggestions are welcomed . I have visualized the data present in big query , in tableau and i want to know are there any other visualization tools cause tableau is paid where as i want to visualize the data for free and i want to implement the functionality in iOS app. Please help me on this ..........

have done some r&d and from there i know the data can be visualized by using Google chart any help on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to write a little bit of code, there is a sample appengine app [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/#git%2Fsamples%2Fch08%2Fsensors%2Fcloud%2Fsrc) that runs BigQuery queries and saves the results in a dashboard.

Another good option is to use Apps Script to write queries and chart the results in Google Sheets. Step by step instructions are in the book Google BigQuery Analytics, but you may be able to just read the relevant snippet [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=LDaiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA419&lpg=PA419&dq=google%20apps%20script%20bigquery&source=bl&ots=dDLu0LWpjo&sig=kxaPbFh0NyaU7tsQh-fyCh5SkoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-a1PVJ_AKMagNtWWgyg&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=google%20apps%20script%20bigquery&f=false) or the blog post [here](http://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/). Sample Apps Script code is [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch12/query.gs).

Comment: Thanks it was of great help

Answer (score 5):

My favorite new open source dashboard for BigQuery is re:dash, check it out:

- Code: https://github.com/EverythingMe/redash
- Demo: http://demo.redash.io/

If you have GCE (Google Compute Engine) you can run your own private instance:

- Instructions: https://github.com/EverythingMe/redash/wiki/Setting-up-re:dash-instance
- Currently: `gcutil addimage redash-040b563 gs://redash-images/redash-040b563.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

You can build reports in Google Sheets using [a free BigQuery Reports Add-on](http://goo.gl/9IqjgK).

Benefits:

- No CSV-files or coding required,
- Queries are saved for future use,
- Analysts and developers can create shared SQL-queries with pre-defined variables,
- Variables allow modifying the result without editing SQL-syntax,
- Everything works in Google Cloud.